# Regex pattern for string GET parameter

Tags: php

What is the regex pattern for example.com/profile/test?

I'm using [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/performant-url-routing-with-php-and-regular-expressions-regex-866480493412) snippet for URL routing with regex.

I'm tried to do with this:

```
'path_pattern' => '/^profile\/(?P<user>[a-z_]+)$/',
'controller'   => 'views/profile.php'
```

But it returns: `Undefined index: user in /var/www/html/views/profile.php on line 15`

Comment: What's your actual code; you only show desired input?

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET["user"]; ?>` - for testing purposes only.

Comment: Ok. `$_GET['user']` expects a url parameter called `user` which you likely dont have. Your routing goal appears to want to inspect the whole url, so herein is the problem.